# How to get current Size of button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So as the question suggests I have a button.

And I want to create a Container that has the exact size of the button. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: no, you cannot do that in most cases, why would you want to know that size for? that `Container` should be a button's parent?

Comment: no the container should be separate. When a boolean is false I want to show a progress indicator that is inside a container with the same size of the initial button. I cant wrap the indicator inside the same button type, because it resizes itself dynamically then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `key` property bound to your button and reading its height from that key and setting it to `Container` height on `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` like so:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        buttonHeight = buttonKey.currentContext?.size?.height ?? 0;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  final buttonKey = GlobalKey();
  double buttonHeight = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              key: buttonKey,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('button'),
            ),
            Container(
              height: buttonHeight,
              color: Colors.blue,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'button height container',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the current size of the button, you can open the flutter inspector and just view the button size in your IDE!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just put that button Inside of a container, and copy the height and the width for the new Container

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).